# Image of orthogonal symmetry

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $P=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\textbf{R}^3|x_1+2x_2-3x_3=6\}$, $Q=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\textbf{R}^3|x_1+x_2+x_3=3\}$ and $\sigma:\textbf{R}^3\to\textbf{R}^3$ be an orthogonal symmetry about $P$. I have to find equation describing $\sigma(Q)$ and I want to know how to do that without finding formula for $\sigma$.

Comment: I don't well understand the question.... but, since $Q$ is not orthogonal to $P$, projecting $Q$ in $P$ gives $P$. Is this an answer to your question?

Comment: I think the OP is not so much interested in projecting into $P$ as in reflecting in $P$, i.e. treating $P$ as a giant mirror.

Comment: @EmilioNovati $\textbf{R}^3=P\oplus P^\perp$,  $\sigma(p)=p$ for $p\in P$ and it's linear part (since $\sigma$ is affine), say $S$, is such that $S(v)=v$ for $v\in P$ and $S(v)=-v$ for $v\in P^\perp$. I'm looking for $\sigma(Q)$ but don't want to explicitly find the formula for $\sigma$